# Given an element in a sequence, how to get the previous element?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say I have a Scala list `List("apple", "orange", "banana", "chinese gooseberry")`*. I want to search this list and return either the previous item in the list in relation to an item I already have.

For example: `getPrevious(fruit: String, fruits: List[String]): Option[String]` should return

- `Some("apple")` if I call it with a `fruit` arg of `"orange"`;
- `Some("banana")` for  `"chinese gooseberry"`;
- `None` if I call it with `"apple"` (no previous element exists) or `"potato"` (not present in the list).

Easily done imperatively, but how can I do this in an elegant functional manner? The best I can come up with is the following:

```
def previous(fruit: String, fruits: List[String]): Option[String] =
  fruits.sliding(2)
  .filter { case List(previous, current) => current == fruit }
  .toList
  .headOption
  .map { case List(previous, current) => previous }
```

It works, but it isn't elegant or efficient. I particularly hate converting the `filter` iterator `toList`. How can I improve it?

(*as an aside, is `List` the best collection to use for a `sliding` iteration?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a case where just straight up recursion and pattern matching is both efficient and easier to read:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def getPrevious(fruit: String, fruits: List[String]): Option[String] = fruits match  {
  case Nil               => None
  case x :: `fruit` :: _ => Some(x)
  case _ :: xs           => getPrevious(fruit, xs)
}
```

Comment: Definitely agreed on the second point - this looks more readable to me.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a shorter version using `collectFirst`:

```
def previous(fruit: String, fruits: List[String]): Option[String] =
    fruits.sliding(2).collectFirst{ case List(previous, `fruit`) => previous}
```

Note the backticks surrounding `fruit` to match the parameter value. Using `collectFirst` will also stop at the first match, rather than running through the entire iterator with `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

The first simple solution that comes to mind is:

```
import scala.util.Try
def previous(fruit: String, fruits: List[String]) = Try(fruits(fruits.indexOf(fruit) - 1)).toOption
```

There should certainly be more efficient ones.

Comment: This looks clever but cost of throwing exceptions is high + exceptions should be used in exceptional cases, they are not values which goes against FP principles. Nonetheless I like the idea ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know, it also iterates the whole `List` twice in the worst case. Indexing is sadly `O(n)` on `List`. It was just a crazy idea. ;)